# extract property values from array

Tags: typescript, generics

Is there some way to extract property values from array?

```js
const d = [{id: 'Cat'}, {id: 'Dog'}]

type ids = ??? //insert code here, type should be 'Cat' | 'Dog'
```

(It would also work if it generates a const enum)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you declare `d` with `as const`, you can extract the information like this:

```
const d = [{id: 'Cat'}, {id: 'Dog'}] as const

type IDs = typeof d[number]["id"]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=3&ssc=34&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJjAvDA2gbwJZwFwwOQDCAhlHgL4A0MmO+AIiAObkC6MREMokUAsAFACoATwAOAUxgBJOp2QiJIAGbwUYAK4BbAEbiATixQAiLEZZA)

Comment: To add an explanation why `as const` is needed: literal types won't work otherwise, so you'd only be able to get the less strict `string`. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types

Comment: is it possible to do `as const` when importing a json file?

Comment: I would say no. It would not work with an imported json file. This only works with object literals in your typescript code.

Comment: Here is an open issue https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32063 for allowing to import json with `as const`. So this may be possible in the future.